# nVIDIA GPU clock64() values - meaning and initialization/resetting

Tags: cuda, clock

The `clock64()` device-side function in CUDA gives us some sort of clock ticks value. The documentation [says](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#time-function):

> when executed in device code, [clock64()] returns the value of a per-multiprocessor counter that is incremented every clock cycle.

A little program  I wrote to examine `clock64()` behavior suggests that you get about the same initial value when you start a kernel at different points in (wall clock) time (without rebooting the machine or "manually" resetting the device). For my specific case that seems to be about 5,200,000 to 6,400,000 for the first kernel a process starts. Also, the values increase slightly from SM to SM - while it's not clear they should be at all related, or perhaps, if they are, perhaps they should actually be identical.

I also found that with the next kernel launch, the initial `clock64()` value increases - but then after some more kernel runs jumps down to a much lower value (e.g. 350,000 or so) and gradually climbs again.  There doesn't seem to be a consistent pattern to this behavior (that I can detect with a few runs and manual inspection).

So, my questions are:

- Does `clock64()` actually return clock ticks, or something else that's time-based?
- In what ways is `clocks64()` SM-specific, and in what ways are the values on different SMs related?
- What resets/re-initializes the `clock64()` value?
- Can I initialize the `clock64()` value(s) myself?

Comment: What do you want to know this for other than to satisfy curiosity? The only use case I can see is using differences to time parts of code.

Comment: However there is also a `%globaltimer` special PTX register that you might be interested in if you want to record time differences between events on different SMs.

Comment: @tera: Well, curiosity is a valid reason, but to satisfy _your_ curiosity... I want to know if I should worry about wrap-around or not with a 64-bit counter.

Comment: It looks like a hardware counter, per sm. I see no reason for a meaningfull initial value. There is no reason why your blocks would be executed on the same sm from one call to another, and no reason why counters on SMs would have values that look alike - if the microkernel on the card sets the values, it might take a few millis to boot each, and then, explain you million ticks value difference. Finally, the loop on the clock64 should be once every 700 years. By then, you will have some time to upgrade your code.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET: Well, I don't see the reason too, but it seems the different SMs do have correlated values (I'm running kernels which have enough blocks to require many SMs). Also, if I don't know whether the initial value is meaningful or not, I can't know whether it's close to wrapping around or not.

Comment: You don't need to worry about wraparound because it's only meaningful to look at differences of values. And they will be correct even if the absolute value wrapped around in between.

Comment: @tera: wrap-around will may result in a negative difference, or worse - a difference exceeding the bounds of the (signed) type.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: And can I count on it never being set to some high value? If so, that at least answers my immediate concern, although what you describe doesn't quite square with the frequent drop in value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does `clock64()` actually return clock ticks, or something else that's time-based?

`clock64()` reads a per-SM 64-bit counter (it actually returns a signed result, so 63 bits available).  The clock source for this counter is the GPU core clock.  The core clock frequency is discoverable using the `deviceQuery` sample code, for example.   As an order-of-magnitude estimate, most CUDA GPUs I am familiar with have a clock period that is on the order of 1 nanosecond.  If we multiply 2^63 by 1 nanosecond, I compute a counter rollover period of approximately 300 years.

> In what ways is `clock64()` SM-specific, and in what ways are the values on different SMs related?

There is no guarantee that the counter in a particular SM has any defined relationship to a counter in another SM, other than that they will have the same clock period.

> What resets/re-initializes the `clock64()` value?

The counter will be reset at some unspecified point, somewhere between machine power-on and the first point at which you access the counter for that SM.  The counter may additionally be reset at any point when a SM is inactive, i.e. has no resident threadblocks.  The counter should not be reset during any interval when one or more threadblocks are active on the SM.

> Can I initialize the `clock64()` value(s) myself?

You cannot.  You have no direct control over the counter value.

Comment: Based on this answer, I've written [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/178601/64513).